# On-line random forests by adding more single Decisions Trees

Tags: random-forest, online-learning

A Random Forest (RF) is created by an ensemble of Decision Trees's (DT). By using bagging, each DT is trained in a different data subset. Hence, **is there any way of implementing an on-line random forest by adding more decision tress on new data?**

For example, we have 10K samples and train 10 DT's. Then we get 1K samples, and instead of training again the full RF, we add a new DT. The prediction is done now by the Bayesian average of 10+1 DT's.

In addition, if we keep all the previous data, the new DT's can be trained mainly in the new data, where the probability of picking a sample is weighted depending how many times have been already picked.

Answer (score 9):

There's [a recent paper on this subject](http://www.vision.cs.chubu.ac.jp/CV-R/pdf/AmirICCVW2009.pdf) (*On-line Random Forests*), coming from computer vision. [Here's an implementation](http://www.ymer.org/amir/software/online-random-forests/), and a presentation: [Online random forests in 10 minutes](http://www.slideshare.net/CvilleDataScience/online-random-forest-in-10-minutes)

Comment: The implementation that you mentioned follows a tree-growing strategy, like Mondrian forests (http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2673). Hence, the number of trees is constant while the number of splits is increased. My question focuses on increasing the number of trees for new samples while remaining untouched the previously trained trees.

Comment: Like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87237/trend-analysis-of-feature-importance-over-time-in-r)? Don't you also want to drop trees if appropriate?

Comment: Thank you. This is more similar to what I am looking for. In this case, the use RF for feature selection of time-variant signals. However, the specific implementation and validity of the method is quite unclear, do you know if they published anything (Google didn't help)?

Comment: [Calculating Feature Importance in Data Streams With Concept Drift Using Online Random Forest](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/19ccixj5ey5ldwpp63x9VGqpTR2Hr-D4nM3l1NRPSPFo/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I can see that they actually update all the previous trees using a tree-growing strategy, and I am interested in creating new DT's with the new data while keeping untouched the old trees.